# how to unzip epub format file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, epub

I am developing an Ebook reader for iPhone that loads ePUB file. I would like to know how would I unzip ePUB file format. Is there any examples around?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 21):

Unzipping is easier than zipping. Just change extension to .zip and use regular zip tool.

Or on Mac, in Terminal, use

unzip file.epub

Comment: the OP has been asking this question in various forms for a while now, I think she or he wants someone to supply sample Objective C code so they don't have to learn anything much about EPUB

Comment: We might tell him that the zip format is well documented, that the EPUB standard tells us very precisely which zip version is to be used for ePub, and that the zlib library is available as part of iOS. Maybe add that Google or Bing will easily find all that information. And as a bonus (I wish someone had told me): He'll need the class NSURLProtocol.